# How to prevent nuget from redundantly restoring packages after opening solution in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2017, nuget

Every time i'm opening a solution in Visual Studio 2017 which uses Net.Core SDK it restores packages. It happens all the time, even if i close the solution and open it again.

Why does not it keep a local track of what nuget packages are present on the machine?

Can i make it to behave more logically and first to check it locally for the package presence and to restore it only if it can not be found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Question:** How to prevent nuget from redundantly restoring packages after opening solution in Visual Studio 2017

There is currently no way to disable auto-restore explicitly. Check following thread for more details:

[How do I disable restoring NuGet packages while starting the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45437261/how-do-i-disable-restoring-nuget-packages-while-starting-the-solution)

> The restore you are seeing there is **Auto-Restore** which will only run
>   on SDK based projects.
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore#automatic-restore-in-visual-studio
>
> There is currently no way to disable auto-restore explicitly but you
>   can disable restore itself. Note that this will disable all restore
>   (on build/rebuild & solution right click restore)

Besides, you do not need to disable it, check the another reason below:

> **Question:** Can i make it to behave more logically and first to check it locally
>   for the package presence and to restore it only if it can not be
>   found?

What nuget is doing now is exactly what you want it to do. Check:

[Forcing restore from package sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore#forcing-restore-from-package-sources):

> By default, NuGet restore operations use packages from the
>   global-packages and http-cache folders.

So, the restore you are seeing when you open the solution is just check if the packages exists in the global-packages, if not, then nuget start to restore the packages. If packages are exists, nuget does not execute the restore operation. And checking time is very short, about tens of ms. You don't have to worry too much about it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Strange thing - i developed a solution at home, then packed it, unpacked at work - i see all the packages in the folder. But it starts to check or restore the packages. Looks like it takes longer than just to reopen the solution on the same computer. First time it took 36 seconds, and after unpacking and opening the same solution it took 10 seconds. If i just reopen this solution it takes 430 milliseconds.

Comment: and the third time - i unpacked zip archive and opened the solution - and it restored the packages in 2272 milliseconds. So it probably checks the global cache. But i don't know, maybe after some time it tries to restore it anyway. Because i developed it yesterday, zipped it, unpacked it at home and did some work - not adding any new packages. Next day i brought it to work, and it took it 38 seconds to restore.

Comment: I have found why this can happen - the http-cache has an expiration of 30 minutes. http‑cache  The Visual Studio Package Manager (NuGet 3.x+) and the dotnet tool store copies of downloaded packages in this cache (saved as .dat files), organized into subfolders for each package source. Packages are not expanded, and the cache has an expiration time of 30 minutes.

    Windows: %localappdata%\NuGet\v3-cache
    Mac/Linux: ~/.local/share/NuGet/v3-cache
    Override using the NUGET_HTTP_CACHE_PATH environment variable.

Comment: Now, i unpacked the solution into the folder and opened it. The result: Time Elapsed: 00:00:26.4429320
========== Finished ==========
Could you explain please why it restores for 26 seconds instead of milliseconds?

Comment: @Maxim T, What I said `about tens of ms` is for the default time, not for all situations. Time is affected by many factors, for example, the number of projects, the packages installed, computer performance... and so on. You can try to create a default blank .net core project in the new solution, when you close and re-open the solution, it only takes `about tens of ms`. Besides, if you have move the solution or do something about nuget packages, it will take more time to check it.

Comment: @Maxim T, How about this issue now? If above answer resolved your question? If yes, you could accept it as an answer. This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread. If not, let me to know what is your problem now, I will keep follow :).

Comment: Behaves the same.  I just accepted that it works in such a way. The good thing, that the switched off network does not prevent restoration - because the packages are all in the cache. But it takes the same 20+ seconds